# Is "rolling-wave planning" catered for in PRINCE2?

Tags: planning, project-management-style, prince2, pmbok

I am struggling to bridge my PMBOK knowledge with a colleague that follows PRINCE2.

I wonder if someone could help me understand whether PRINCE2 has the concept of "rolling-wave planning".

From:[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling-wave_planning)

> Rolling-wave planning is the process of project planning in waves as the project proceeds and later details become clearer; similar to the techniques used in agile software development approaches like Scrum. (...) The concepts of rolling-wave planning and progressive elaboration are techniques covered in the Project Management Body of Knowledge

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling-wave_planning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prince2, project are divided into stages. At the end of the stage, there is Managing a Stage Boundary.  http://prince2.wiki/Managing_a_Stage_Boundary

from the link:

> Purpose
>
> The purpose of Managing a Stage Boundary process has two parts:
>
> The Project Manager has to provide the Project Board with an overview
>   of the performance of the current stage, update the Project Plan and
>   Business Case, and create a Stage Plan for the next stage.
>
> This information will enable the Project Board to review the current
>   stage, approve the next stage, review the updated Project Plan, and
>   confirm Continued Business Justification.

Ideally, this is the time where you will assess the current stage as you may discover some details that will require some update to the previous document which may make things clearer and will use those details on the next stage. (e.g. in the previous document, it was specified that the estimated timings to acquire data should be from 50msec to 100msec, but you found out from the last stage that 50msec is not enough and may need to be around 1msec to be able to get good readings).